# Extract function to Add month in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have SQL query as follow

```
MONTH(ADD_MONTHS(TRAN_DATE,1))
```

and then in oracle extract function for month I have

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TRAN_DATE)
```

So now how do I add month in Extract function in oracle query like SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean SQL-Server when talking about SQL, is this what you want?

```
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS( tran_date, 1 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might work for you:

```
select EXTRACT( MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, 1 ) ) from dual
```